# Require to store Publish Artifacts of each stages in single directory over azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Each stages stores its own publish artifacts, but can we store it in a common place where we keep placing publish artifacts of every build and download from there as an when require ?

And also that common storage should not be azure repository nor azure blob storage, instead simply over azure pipeline.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish pipeline artifact out of the box supports to publish artifact to file share on Azure Storage Account. However if you want to put your arifacts outside of Azure you need to consider external provider like [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension). There is no other options out of the box. However keep in mind that your aritifacts are mostly archive so you can even upoad then to FTP if you want, however the question is actually why you need this and if benefit is greater than effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing is I am creating pipeline which in future going to operate by end-user who is non-technical. And he require all his publish artifact to be at single place. I have tried several ways in Azure Pipeline, but each publish artifact is showing under its respective run(stages), where I am not getting any option where azure devops shows me all publish artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

> Require to store Publish Artifacts of each stages in single directory over azure pipeline

I am afraid it is impossible to store Publish Artifacts of each stages in single directory over azure pipeline.

That because the azure pipeline is used for building and publishing, not for storage. It will only temporarily store the artifacts generated by the pipeline associated with the pipeline.

For your situation, you could create a network folder, then publish the artifact to the network folder for each stage:

[image]